# Preventing access to file in .htaccess results in error on request of any page from server?

Tags: .htaccess

i have a logging folder, where i log events, i want to include it in the admin panel or be able to search in it, but i dont want it to be accessible outside of localhost.

So i tried

```
<Files /var/chroot/home/content/59/10667659/html/mylogs/log.html>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

But this results in a 500 something error on all of my pages?

```
/var/chroot/home/content/59/10667659/html
```

is

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<Files>` container does not work that way. From the [Apache core doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files):

> The  directive limits the scope of the enclosed directives by **filename**. It is comparable to the  and  directives. It should be matched with a  directive. The directives given within this section will be applied to any object with a **basename (last component of filename)** matching the specified filename.

So you can say:

```
<Files "log.html">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

Or if you want it to apply only in a specific directory, like in `/mylogs/`, then create the htaccess file in there and add the above `<Files>` container.